# Is it feasible to pre-compile (Maven/Gradle) Apache Daffodil DataProcessor for use as a dependency in a separate parsing app?

Tags: parsing, java-11, dfdl

Apache Daffodil newby...

Trying to save start up time with an Apache Daffodil message parsing application.

Just wanted to know if it were possible (or feasible) to pre-compile an Apache Daffodil "DataProcessor" object (with a designated schema, of course) - and then to use it as a build dependency for a separate application using Daffodil parsing.
---I.e., versus awaiting the schema compile at runtime

Answer (score 0):

The Daffodil API does provide methods to serialize and deserialize a `DataProcessor` via the `DataProcessor#save` and `Compiler#reload` methods.

For example, to save the DataProcessor to a file:

```java
DataProcessor dp = ...;

FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(filePath);
dp.save(fc);
```

To reload that file to a data processor:

```java
FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(filePath);
DataProcessor dp = Compiler.reload(fc);
```

That example is for using a file, but the API supports saving to any `WritableByteChannel` and reloading from any `ReadableByteChannel`.

There aren't any existing Maven/Gradle plugins that automatically do this that I am aware of, but the compile/save could be put in a resource generator, and then reload called at runtime to load the resource.